# Suggestion for angular application (dialog or bottom sheet)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating an application in angular where I have to design a pop up on the right bottom side of the window. There is a feature where I need to add an item and it takes only two input so rather than opening a new page I Want to open a pop up or dialog or bottom sheet to take input. 
I Need suggestions what should I use in sach case. I tried to analyze but not sure what is the perfect chocie for this.
Earlier in angular versions there were concepts of panel but I can not find sach panels in angular 8 or 9. Any replaced item for this in angular.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend looking at how Bootstrap toasts and Material Snackbars work. You can apply their CSS principles to your own custom component. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/toasts/ https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [Bottom Sheet](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview) material component, also called "panel".

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use modal for this case. I recommend this because a `modal.service.ts` can be created and you can use it app wide for basically anything like loading screen,inputs,warning,file upload etc. It is a bit difficult to set up a fully configurable modal service but its worth it.

Comment: did you have a problem with injecting references to dialog and bottom sheet?  for example if that dialog/sheet would close itself

Comment: I did'nt fully understand. can you comment with an example?

Comment: say you had a component that you could use for both desktop and mobile that had a button that closed itself.  Because of how the dialogRef or bottomSheetRef get injected, you'll get an injection error.  anyhow, i ended up just wrapping the shared component in specific components for either dialog or bottom sheet and that worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue recently.
Based on material design system recommendations, bottomsheet is much more intended for mobile devices. So in my case, i use Dialog on desktop/tablet displays, and bottomsheet for mobile devices.